# how from Array of strings take proper value

Tags: reactjs

I would like to take proper value from array of strings that look like this:

```
  const coreAreaUk = [
    data.ce?.basic_competences?.step || "",
    data.ce?.professional_competences?.step || "",
    data.ce?.team_competences?.step || "",
  ];
```

I have map function which uses coreAreaUk. Right now my result is "first sentence, second sentence, third sentence" and I would like to have "first sentence" for basic_component, "second sentence" for professional_competences and "third sentence" for team_competences

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are asking. What are you trying to achieve? What should be the desired result? Can you give some output example of what you are talking about? Please edit your post to reflect that

Comment: Is it that you aren't seeing the contents/data from `basic_competences`, `professional_competences` etc when you map over them?

Comment: for my CSV file I need separate value in each row for basic_competences, professional_competences and team_competences. Right now I have in each row all 3 values together